# Nodes unpublished by SQL query are accessible to anonymous user

Tags: views

This issue is in context of node type product, which means nodes are products here.

Scenario 1 (**Desired behaviour**):

- I've logged in as Admin
- I've Unpublished Node: 12345
- After logged out (or in another browser where I'm not logged in), if I try to access that node, I see "Access denied" message

Scenario 2 (**Undesired behaviour**):

- I'm not logged in Drupal front end or admin
- I'm using a script which executes SQL queries in *node* and *node_revision* tables to update *status* field to 0 to *Unpublish* the node
- After that, if I try to access that node in browser without logged in, I see article image(s) and title: *product description* with pink background but not the rest of the article content.

In permission, Unpublished nodes are not accessible by anonymous users.
Basically I'm new in Drupal and wants to publish/unpublish nodes in bulk (could be in 5-10k) from CSV file.

Can anybody help to fix this issue? I don't want pink background and partially accessibility to the node. It should show "Access denied" message when Unpublished.

Comment: You probably need to clear caches - that's why using the API is usually a better idea, it takes care of that bit for you

Comment: I tried clearing cache with command: `drush cc all` but didn't work

Comment: Try clearing the cache for that node specifically: `entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));`

Comment: Might rebuilding content permissions help here?